# Uploading image in json to send api request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i want to send an image as json to a post api,but when i send the url of the image in json the reponse shows error.But in postman when i send the image with file upload it works.
My json:

```
{
name:"xxx",
image:"someurl"
}
```

my c# code:

```
 {
            string url = "xxxxxxxxxx";

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = null;
            string responseFromServer = "";
            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
           
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 300000;
            // Get the response.
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(jsonREQ);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
            using (webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    responseFromServer = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    sr.Close();
                }
                webResponse.Close();
            }
            return responseFromServer;
        }
```

Here the json request have the json,when i use this i dont get the expected response,but when i use postman with file upload,
[It works ,Kindly suggest me a way to send my image in json.(* have tried base64 and byte,it doesnt work as expected*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zoqP.png)

Comment: Please provide some more information about the error, so that we can help you

Comment: Error is from the other end of the api.All they want is image not the url.Just as how we upload file in postman.They dont accept base64 or byte.

Comment: Is it error 500, what's the description, what's the payload from postman, which headers do you send, what's the identification scheme etc.

Comment: Noo error is not 500.The error is the response from the supplier,they want the file to be inserted jus like postman,kindly see the link i have posted.You may understand my problem.

Comment: You can't send an image, which is binary content, with JSON. Unless you convert your image into base64 string. But the correct way should be to use FormData to upload files.

Comment: Api dont accept base64.FormData,can you post an answer with a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("image", fileInputElement.files[0]);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://example.com/submitform.php");
request.send(formData);
```

And this on the server to upload to another server:

```
string responseString;

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent {
        { new StreamContent(fileStream), @"image", Path.GetFileName(filePath) }
    };

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

    request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
    request.SendChunked = true; // set to true to avoid exception when AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false and ContentLength is not set
    request.Headers.Add("abc", "def");

    request.ContentType = formData.Headers.ContentType.ToString();

    try
    {
        // Get the request stream with the default timeout
        using (Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsyncWithTimeout())
        {
            // Upload the file with no timeout
            await formData.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
        }

        // Get response with the default timeout, and parse the response body
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsyncWithTimeout())
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException("Timeout while uploading file.", ex);
        }
        throw;
    }
}
ResultModel result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultModel>(responseString);
```

These extensions so your upload request won't be timeout if you have a big file or slow connection:

```
public static class WebRequestExtensions
{
    public static async Task<Stream> GetRequestStreamAsyncWithTimeout(this WebRequest request, int? millisecondsTimeout = null)
    {
        Task<Stream> getTask = request.GetRequestStreamAsync();

        if (await Task.WhenAny(getTask, Task.Delay(request.Timeout)) == getTask)
        {
            // task completed without timeout
            return getTask.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            // timeout
            var ex = new TimeoutException();
            throw new WebException(ex.Message, ex, WebExceptionStatus.Timeout, null);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<WebResponse> GetResponseAsyncWithTimeout(this WebRequest request, int? millisecondsTimeout = null)
    {
        Task<WebResponse> getTask = request.GetResponseAsync();

        if (await Task.WhenAny(getTask, Task.Delay(request.Timeout)) == getTask)
        {
            // task completed without timeout
            return getTask.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            // timeout
            var ex = new TimeoutException();
            throw new WebException(ex.Message, ex, WebExceptionStatus.Timeout, null);
        }
    }

    private static T AsyncToSyncWithTimeout<T>(
        Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> begin,
        Func<IAsyncResult, T> end,
        int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        var iar = begin(null, null);
        if (!iar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout))
        {
            var ex = new TimeoutException();
            throw new WebException(ex.Message, ex, WebExceptionStatus.Timeout, null);
        }
        return end(iar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..but,I use c# for api connection

Comment: I've added c# code. You'll need to save your file (that just got uploaded from the browser) to disk first (on the server). Then upload it to another server/API, if that's what you want.